# How can I pass an element as initial state in redux toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to pass an element as my initial state. like this:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Home } from "@mui/icons-material";
export const setIconSlice = createSlice({
  name: "IconSet",
  initialState: {
    icon: <Home />,
  },
  reducers: {
    setIcon: (state, action) => {
      state.icon = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
export const { setIcon } = setIconSlice.actions;
export default setIconSlice.reducer;
```

I want to have *home* icon of material UI as my initial state but as you can guess I get

> A non-serializable value was detected in the state

I tried to disable `serializable check` from store middleware. Error goes away but I still can't see any icon.

is there anyway to pass an element as a state? I don't get any error with `useState` ***but I want it globally in my entire app*** so I don't want to pass it from element to element with `useState`

Comment: Why do you want to have an icon in the initialState, it is going to change at some point?

Comment: @MaxCode yes it is going to change when use clicks on menu items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes, redux forces you to use serializable —like plain object— elements in the state.

I was thinking on making use of a value —enums— that would let you import previously imported elements with `lazy`.

```
  initialState: {
    // icon values will be strings
    icon: 'home',
  },
```

And in your component try this:

```
// lazy import the components for code-splitting
const HomeIcon = React.lazy(() => import('./Home'));
const SearchIcon = React.lazy(() => import('./Search'));

// get the current icon from the state
const icon = useSelector(state => state.icon);

// helper
const getStateIcon = () => {
    // return lazy loaded element depending of the icon string value
    switch (icon) {
        case 'home':
            return <HomeIcon />;
        case 'search':
            return <SearchIcon />;
        default:
            return <HomeIcon />;

    }
}

// in your jsx file
<React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    {getStateIcon()}
</React.Suspense>
```

This way you will have the option for code-splitting and make your loading time lighter.

Check how how `lazy` works in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-forked-36jvzz)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string to save icon

```
initialState:{ icon: 'home'}
```

In App.js (or any component you need to use icon)

```
const icon = useSelector(state=>state.icon)
```

Then, render Home Component conditionally based on icon stored in redux

```
icon ==='home' && <Home/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend to map the name of the icon to a component instance, redux does not like things it can't serialize for a reason:

```
// Import all icons you want to make available
import { Home, OtherIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";

// Map their name to component instances
export const icons = {
    home: <Home />,
    othericon: <OtherIcon />
};

// Now you simply put 'home' (as a string) in redux for the initial state

// When using the icon, retrieve it like this:
const iconPath = useSelector(state => state.iconPath);
const icon = icons[iconPath];
```